# Dash between consecutive numbers

Tags: r

I would like to split a numeric vector in the positions of non-consecutive numbers. So I would like to convert the following numeric vector
data = c(18,20:25,28:30)

to string
data = c("18","-","20","21","22","23","24","25","-", "28","29","30")
Is there any way to do that?
Many thanks for considering my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R using `tapply` :

```
data = c(18,20:25,28:30)
result <- unlist(tapply(data, cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(data) > 1)), function(x) 
           c('-', x)), use.names = FALSE)[-1]

#[1] "18" "-"  "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "-"  "28" "29" "30"
```

In every group of consecutive numbers prepend the sequence with `"-"`.

Comment: Great answer with `tapply`! +1!, I always forget it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one base R option using `split` + `cumsum`

```
unname(
  unlist(
    sapply(
      split(v, cumsum(c(1, diff(v) != 1))),
      function(x) c("-", as.character(x))
    )
  )[-1]
)
```

which gives

```
[1] "18" "-"  "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "-"  "28" "29" "30"
```

**Data**

```
v <- c(18, 20:25, 28:30)
```